# z-index is not working

Tags: html, z-index, css3pie

Why item with z-index 410 (#imgth_1) is displayed below the item with z-index 130 ( #imgth_2 ) ? How it looks you can see here :
Example is https://typejoy.biz/dev/cssBasicNav33/en/mandalaNav#imgth_1

I found that you can apply z-index only for items with absolute, relative or fixed positioning. The example is in absolute, but i have tried also fixed positioning.

```
 <!--
z-index  100  .leavesCont  
z-index  105  .large leave one  
z-index  110   .pItemWrap

z-index  130   a.aThumbCl img
z-index  140   a.aThumbCl img span
z-index  150   a.aThumbCl
z-index  300   div.stendOverLay
z-index  310   div.stendOverLayWrapIn
z-index  410   div.stendOverLay div.stendOverLayWrapIn img
z-index  450   div.stendOverLay div.stendOverLayWrapIn div.stendClose
 -->
```

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    span.leavesCont {
      display: block;
      height: 20em;
      left: calc(50% - 10em);
      position: absolute;
      top: calc(50% - 10em);
      width: 20em;
    }
    
    .leave {
      border-top: 0.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
      height: 12.5em;
      position: absolute;
      width: 6.5em;
      /*overflow: hidden;*/
    
      border-radius: 50%;
      box-shadow: 0 1em 2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      left: calc(50% - 6.25em);
      top: calc(50% - 12.5em);
      transform-origin: 50% 12.5em;
    }
    
    
    
    .one {
      background: rgba(16, 63, 236, 0.75);
      transform: rotateZ(225deg);
    }
    
    .two {
      background: rgba(37, 172, 162, 0.75);
      transform: rotateZ(180deg);
    }

       
        
        div.pItemWrap {
            position : relative;
        }
        
        /* better float left */ 
        div.pItemWrap div.navTWrap {  
            display: flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap: wrap;
            align-items: center; justify-content: space-between;
        }
         
        div.pItemWrap div.stendOverLay {
            position : absolute;
            width:100vw !important; height:100vh !important; 
            left:0px; top:0px;
            background : blue; 
        }
        
        div.stendOverLayWrapIn {
            position : relative; 
        }
        
        div.pItemWrap div.stendOverLay div.stendOverLayWrapIn img { 
            position : absolute; 
            display:block; 
            left:50px; top:50px;
            width:700px; height:700px; 
        }
        div.stendOverLay div.stendOverLayWrapIn a.stendClose {
            position : absolute; 
            display:block; 
            left:250px; top:250px;
        }
        
    
        div.pItemWrap div.stendOverLay:target { display: block;  width:auto; height:auto;  }

        
        #imgth_1:target { transform: rotateZ(-225deg); }
        #imgth_2:target { transform: rotateZ(-180deg); }
    

        div.pItemWrap div.stendOverLay {
            display: none;
        }
        
    .leavesCont  { z-index : 100  }
    .large.leave  { z-index : 105 }
    .pItemWrap { z-index : 110  }
    a.aThumbCl img { z-index : 130 }
    a.aThumbCl img span { z-index : 140 }
    a.aThumbCl { z-index : 150 }
    div.stendOverLay { z-index : 300 }
    div.stendOverLayWrapIn { z-index : 310 }
    div.stendOverLay div.stendOverLayWrapIn img { z-index : 410 }
    div.stendOverLay div.stendOverLayWrapIn a.stendClose { z-index : 450 }
```

```html
    <span class="leavesCont">
        
        <div class="large leave one" id="large-leave-one">  
        
            <div class="pItemWrap" >
               <!-- simle a with text  <a href="#imgth_1" class="aThumbCl" >4</a> -->
                <a href="#imgth_1" class="aThumbCl"  >    
                <img src="<?php echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_300_30_c1_.jpg"; ?>" alt="image 1" >
                    <span class="thumbTitle" id="thumbTitle_4" >Title image-1</span>
                </a>  
    
                
    
                <div class="stendOverLay lb-overlay" id="imgth_1">
                    <div class="stendOverLayWrapIn" >
                        <div class="test" >  TEST </div>  
                        <img class="m100n50"
                        src="aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_300_30_c1_.jpg"
                        sizes="(max-width: <?php echo $vdArr["$mediaWidth_2t"]; ?>) 50vw, 25vw" 
                        srcset="<?php  echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_300_30_c1_.jpg"; ?> 200w,
                        <?php echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_560_30.jpg"; ?>  400w,
                        <?php echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_900_30.jpg"; ?>  600w "
                        alt="image01"
                        /><!-- img of large window -->
    
                     
                            <!-- clicking ny anchor the clost he large window and any other effect from anchors. In radios - only if the same name. In checkboxes - does not affect - you have to clikck the same checkbox -->
                            <a href="#page" class="stendClose lb-close">x Close</a>
                   
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>      
        
        </div> 
        
        <div class="large leave two">
            
    
        <div class="pItemWrap" >
               <!-- simle a with text  <a href="#imgth_2" class="aThumbCl" >4</a> -->
                <a href="#imgth_2" class="aThumbCl"  >    
                <img src="<?php echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_300_30_c1_.jpg"; ?>" alt="image 2" >
                    <span class="thumbTitle" id="thumbTitle_2" >Title image-2</span>
                </a>  
    
                
    
                <div class="stendOverLay lb-overlay" id="imgth_2">
                    <div class="stendOverLayWrapIn" >
                        <div class="test" >  TEST </div>  
                        <img class="m100n50"
                        src="aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_300_30_c1_.jpg"
                        sizes="(max-width: <?php echo $vdArr["$mediaWidth_2t"]; ?>) 50vw, 25vw" 
                        srcset="<?php  echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_300_30_c1_.jpg"; ?> 200w,
                        <?php echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_560_30.jpg"; ?>  400w,
                        <?php echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_900_30.jpg"; ?>  600w "
                        alt="image02"
                        /><!-- img of large window -->
    
                     
                            <!-- clicking ny anchor the clost he large window and any other effect from anchors. In radios - only if the same name. In checkboxes - does not affect - you have to clikck the same checkbox -->
                            <a href="#page" class="stendClose lb-close">x Close</a>
                   
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>      
        </div>
    
    </span>
```

Comment: a.aThumbCl img span assumes the span is a child to IMG instead of sibling relationship as such cannot read the span, consider using a.aThumbCl span instead or a.aThumbCl img > span (sorry am not with my system to confirm)

Comment: I think this has more to do with you markup 's nesting than about an issue with z-index. Given the same nesting level z-index plays a role IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that leaves were separate context compared to large picture inside them, thus large picture in the one leave could not overlap the other leave.

I found detailed explanation here : https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

The solution was

1)to remove

2)to remove

3) to add leave classes to

This also simplifies transformation, because i do not need to rerotate the large image.

The code is here :

```
<style>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

span.leavesCont {
  display: block;
  height: 20em;
  left: calc(50% - 10em);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 10em);
  width: 20em;
}

.leave {
  border-top: 0.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  height: 12.5em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 6.5em;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/

  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1em 2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  left: calc(50% - 6.25em);
  top: calc(50% - 12.5em);
  transform-origin: 50% 12.5em;
}



.one {
  background: rgba(16, 63, 236, 0.75);
  transform: rotateZ(225deg);
}

.two {
  background: rgba(37, 172, 162, 0.75);
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}


/* Navigation */
    a.aThumbCl,  a.aThumbCl img {
        display : block;
        width : 250px; height: 250px;
    }


    div.pItemWrap {
        position : relative;
    }

    /* better float left */ 
    div.pItemWrap div.navTWrap {  
        display: flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center; justify-content: space-between;
    }

   /*  div.pItemWrap  */
    div.stendOverLay {
        position : absolute;
        width:100vw !important; height:100vh !important; 
        left:0px; top:0px;
        background : blue; 
    }

    div.stendOverLayWrapIn {
        position : relative; 
    }

    /*div.pItemWrap */
    div.stendOverLay div.stendOverLayWrapIn img { 
        position : absolute; 
        display:block; 
        left:50px; top:50px;
        width:700px; height:700px; 
    }
    /*div.stendOverLay */
    div.stendOverLayWrapIn a.stendClose {
        position : absolute; 
        display:block; 
        left:250px; top:250px;
    }


    /* div.pItemWrap */
    div.stendOverLay:target { display: block;  width:auto; height:auto;  }

    #imgth_1:target #large-leave-two { z-index: -100; border: 1px solid red; }
    #imgth_2:target #large-leave-one { z-index: -100; border: 1px solid red; }


    div.stendOverLay {
        display: none;
    }

.leavesCont  { z-index : 100  }
.large.leave  { z-index : 105 }
.pItemWrap { z-index : 110  }
a.aThumbCl img { z-index : 130 }
a.aThumbCl img span { z-index : 140 }
a.aThumbCl { z-index : 150 }
div.stendOverLay { z-index : 300 }
div.stendOverLayWrapIn { z-index : 310 }
div.stendOverLay div.stendOverLayWrapIn img { z-index : 410 }
div.stendOverLay div.stendOverLayWrapIn a.stendClose { z-index : 450 }

</style>




<span class="leavesCont">

            <a href="#imgth_1" class="aThumbCl large leave one"  >    
            <img src="<?php echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_300_30_c1_.jpg"; ?>" alt="image 1" >
                <span class="thumbTitle" id="thumbTitle_4" >Title image-1</span>
            </a>  



            <div class="stendOverLay lb-overlay" id="imgth_1">
                <div class="stendOverLayWrapIn" >
                    <div class="test" >  TEST </div>  
                    <img class="m100n50"
                    src="aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_300_30_c1_.jpg"
                    sizes="(max-width: <?php echo $vdArr["$mediaWidth_2t"]; ?>) 50vw, 25vw" 
                    srcset="<?php  echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_300_30_c1_.jpg"; ?> 200w,
                    <?php echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_560_30.jpg"; ?>  400w,
                    <?php echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_900_30.jpg"; ?>  600w "
                    alt="image01"
                    /><!-- img of large window -->


                        <a href="#page" class="stendClose lb-close">x Close</a>

                </div>
            </div> 

           <!-- simle a with text  <a href="#imgth_2" class="aThumbCl" >4</a> -->
            <a href="#imgth_2" class="aThumbCl large leave two"  >    
            <img src="<?php echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_300_30_c1_.jpg"; ?>" alt="image 2" >
                <span class="thumbTitle" id="thumbTitle_2" >Title image-2</span>
            </a>  



            <div class="stendOverLay lb-overlay" id="imgth_2">
                <div class="stendOverLayWrapIn" >
                    <div class="test" >  TEST </div>  
                    <img class="m100n50"
                    src="aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_300_30_c1_.jpg"
                    sizes="(max-width: <?php echo $vdArr["$mediaWidth_2t"]; ?>) 50vw, 25vw" 
                    srcset="<?php  echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_300_30_c1_.jpg"; ?> 200w,
                    <?php echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_560_30.jpg"; ?>  400w,
                    <?php echo BASE_PUBLIC_IMG . "aboutMe/redphp/dreamstime_xxl_88755164_900_30.jpg"; ?>  600w "
                    alt="image02"
                    /><!-- img of large window -->

                        <a href="#page" class="stendClose lb-close">x Close</a>

                </div>
            </div> 


</span>
```